# Is "We embraced." a complete sentence?

Tags: meaning, verbs, ambiguity, transitivity, is-it-a-sentence

Can someone write "we embraced" to mean "we embraced each other?"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it's very common to use that form of expression to imply that you do something with/to each other. For example, we met, we talked, we shook hands, we played golf, we hugged, we kissed.

Comment: Another example that pops to mind is .. too vulgar to list here :)

Answer (score 2):

It is perfectly well to write "we embraced" to mean "we embraced each other".

Answer (score 0):

The simplest sentences in English contain a single independent clause. That means that they:

1. Contain a subject
2. Contain a verb
3. Express a complete thought

Apply those tests and you'll see that the answer is "yes": your sentence has a subject ("we"), a verb ("to embrace" in the simple past tense) and conveys a complete thought (i.e. is not dependent on any other clause to complete the meaning).